# How to use WITH in a Postgres function?

Tags: postgresql, common-table-expression

How to write with as in the function? I want to write a recursive function to calculate the weight of a car. It gave me error like :
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "WITH"

```
create or replace function aggregateWeight(p integer)
returns int as
$$ 
begin
    if p in (select p.pid
        from parts p) then
        return (select p.weight
                from parts p)
    else
        return
        WITH RECURSIVE included_parts(pid, sid, quantity) AS (
        SELECT ps.pid, ps.sid, ps.quantity
        FROM partSubPart ps
        UNION ALL
        SELECT pr.pid, ps.sid, pr.quantity*ps.quantity
        FROM included_parts pr, partSubPart ps
        WHERE ps.pid = pr.sid
        )
        SELECT sum(pr.quantity*p.weight)
        FROM included_parts pr, parts p
        where pr.sid in (select p.pid from parts p)
        GROUP BY pid;
end;
$$ language sql;
```

Comment: `RETURN (WITH ... AS (...) SELECT ...);`

Comment: You can't use `IF` in a `language sql` function. You need `language plpgsql` for that.

Answer (score 0):

Try to surround the query with parentheses.

You are also missing an `END IF;` after the `ELSE`.